# Calling ARM Assembly file from another

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I am currently following the example for RPIA-1 that shows how to use internal functions with ARM Assembler on a Raspberry Pi.

However, what I am wanting to do is separate the function mult_by_5 and create it as it's own assembly (.s) file and call it from the main program.

I am unsure where to start, since the book predominately talks about internal functions and does not mention much on externally calling a function. I tried defining a .global mult_by_5 file, but that doesn't seem to work.

If I wanted to separate mult_by_5 into it's own file, how would I define this file and properly call it back to the main program?

```
 /* -- printf02.s */
2 .data
3
4 .balign 4 @ First message
5 message1: .asciz "Hey, type a number: "
6 .balign 4 @ Second message
7 message2: .asciz "%d times 5 is %d\n"
8 .balign 4 @ Format pattern for scanf
9 scan_pattern: .asciz "%d"
10 .balign 4 @ Where scanf will store the number read
11 number_read: .word 0
12 .balign 4
13 return: .word 0
14 .balign 4
15 return2: .word 0
16
17 .text
18
19 /* mult_by_5 function */
57
9. Functions
20 mult_by_5:
21 ldr r1, =return2 @ r1 <- &return2
22 str lr, [r1] @ *r1 <- lr
23
24 add r0, r0, r0, LSL #2 @ r0 <- r0 + 4*r0
25
26 ldr lr, =return2 @ lr <- &return2
27 ldr lr, [lr] @ lr <- *lr
28 bx lr @ return to main using lr
29
30 .global main
31 main:
32 ldr r1, =return @ r1 <- &return
33 str lr, [r1] @ *r1 <- lr
34
35 ldr r0, =message1 @ r0 <- &message1
36 bl printf @ call to printf
37
38 ldr r0, =scan_pattern @ r0 <- &scan_pattern
39 ldr r1, =number_read @ r1 <- &number_read
40 bl scanf @ call to scanf
41
42 ldr r0, =number_read @ r0 <- &number_read
43 ldr r0, [r0] @ r0 <- *r0
44 bl mult_by_5
45
46 mov r2, r0 @ r2 <- r0
47 ldr r1, =number_read @ r1 <- &number_read
48 ldr r1, [r1] @ r1 <- *r1
49 ldr r0, =message2 @ r0 <- &message2
50 bl printf @ call to printf
51
52 ldr lr, =return @ lr <- &return
53 ldr lr, [lr] @ lr <- *lr
54 bx lr @ return from main using lr
55
56 /* External */
57 .global printf
58 .global scanf
```

Comment: Do you see the `.global` directive used with`main`, `printf` and `scanf`.  For `main`, since it is defined within the file, `.global` is telling the system that someone outside this file can call this function.  For `printf` and `scanf`, as they are used but not defined in the file, `.global` says these are defined in other files.

Comment: @ErikEidt So I would define the mult_by_5 function as .global mult_by_5 and it would be accessible by main?

Comment: Yes, you use the .global directive once *in each file* that wants to *either* export or import the symbol.

Comment: @ErikEidt This resolved my issue at hand. However, how would I pass values to this function as well?

Comment: Typically the difference between internal vs. exported/imported doesn't change how we pass parameters (x86 not withstanding). Look up the [Calling Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), the term for how parameters and return values are transferred, for the pi.  I think you'll find that the first four parameters use r0,r1,r2,r3, respectively, after that use the stack.  The return value goes in r0 before a function leaves.